# Pytest ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, pytest

I'm following the flaskr tutorial [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/tests/), and I'm struggling with running tests.

```
    ➜  pytest
    ImportError while loading conftest 'flaskr_app/tests/conftest.py'.
    tests/conftest.py:5: in <module>
    from ..flaskr import create_app
    E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Pytest seems to be complaining about relative imports. Here is how I set up the import in `conftest.py`:

```python
    import os
    import tempfile
    
    import pytest
    from ..flaskr import create_app
    from ..flaskr import get_db, init_db
```

Here's how my project directory looks like.

```
    ➜  tree
    .
    ├── flaskr
    │   ├── MANIFEST.in
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── auth.py
    │   ├── blog.py
    │   ├── db.py
    │   ├── schema.sql
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── style.css
    │   └── templates
    │       ├── auth
    │       │   ├── login.html
    │       │   └── register.html
    │       ├── base.html
    │       └── blog
    │           ├── create.html
    │           ├── index.html
    │           └── update.html
    ├── instance
    │   └── flaskr.sqlite
    ├── setup.cfg
    ├── setup.py
    └── tests
        ├── conftest.py
        └── data.sql
```

Since the `flaskr` directory resides in the parent directory of `tests` directory, I thought it would be appropriate to import the package `from ..flaskr`.

Can anyone tell me what's causing this error?

Comment: [Please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for existing solutions before posting a question, for example by [copying and pasting error messages into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=attempted+relative+import+with+no+known+parent+package).

Comment: Solution: No need for relative imports, since `flaskr` is installed as pip package. Just use `import flaskr`